# Hiding button after collapse is toggled using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, collapsable

I'm trying to hide the "collapsible" button after it is being pressed.

activities.html:

```
<button class="collapsible"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a></button>
```

Controller.js:

```
    var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var gallery1 = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (gallery1.style.maxHeight){
      gallery1.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      gallery1.style.maxHeight = gallery1.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
});
}
```

I would highly appreciate if someone could help me out of this!

Comment: Please write the code correctly, you didn't forget to add an opening `<a ...>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To hide your `button` **and remove the space occupied by the button on the page**, use `.style.display = 'none'` on the `button` element in the event handler:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");

for (var i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");    
    
    var gallery1 = this.nextElementSibling;
    
    if (gallery1.style.maxHeight) {
      gallery1.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      gallery1.style.maxHeight = gallery1.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
    
    this.style.display = 'none';
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<button class="collapsible"><a><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a></button>
```

**To keep the space occupied by the `button` on the page** and make it  invisible, use `.style.visibility = 'hidden'`:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");

for (var i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");    
    
    var gallery1 = this.nextElementSibling;
    
    if (gallery1.style.maxHeight) {
      gallery1.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      gallery1.style.maxHeight = gallery1.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
    
    this.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<button class="collapsible"><a><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

The shortest solution to your problem is

```
<button class="collapsible" onclick="this.style.display = 'none';">
```